# What pronouns should you use after the pronoun one?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

For instance, if I wanna write: ***one*** should not be judgmental if **they** don't know the truth. Is this correct?

I found this structure *e.g. One is said to communicate successfully when he or she is able to express what he or she feels* is a bit redundant, I have to repeat he or she all the time.

So, what pronoun should I use in order to refer the previous **ONE** when I'm writing in the way in the example sentence?

Comment: Other possibilities:  "One should not be judgmental if one does't know the truth" and "You should not be judgmental if you don't know the truth".  The latter is more common nowadays, I think.

Comment: This has been a quandary for English speakers and writers for ages.  There is no simple answer, since the discussion can quickly devolve into a political/emotional battle.

Comment: *One should obviously continue with the same pronoun one started with.* It just sounds daft to randomly switch to "singular they", in contexts like *One shouldn't pick their nose in public.*

Comment: If it's a pronoun, then use it. _One should not have to resort to using 'they' or 'you' when one means oneself.  They_ and _you_ can be used for non-specific indefinites, and are more common in speech than _one_ is. But _one_ has its own forms and they can be used like any pronoun's forms: _he, him, his, himself; one, one's, oneself_.

Comment: Please do not write *wanna* when you mean *want to*. It makes you seem uneducated and disrespectful.

Comment: @JohnLawler There is an interesting little conversation going on at [Why is this habitual sentence wrong?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525445/why-is-this-habitual-sentence-wrong), which I feel would benefit from your professional input. I wonder if you would be so kind as to take a look, John.

Comment: @tchrist I'm glad you said that and not me. I fear I would have been taken for some patronising British snob.

Answer (score -1):

"ONE" is an Impersonal pronoun and Indefinite pronoun. As Wikipedia has it ,this is gender neutral and for purpose of verb agreement it is a third person singular pronoun although sometimes used with first or second person reference. It can have ' one' or 'he' or "Singular They" as its referential. Since use of "one" is dated, and "He" has a generic overtone, in objective and possessive case, now-a-days singular THEY with plural verb agreement is preferred.

So all your sentences are correct.  Take this  example.

- Taking advantage of delay in answering and editing, one in his/ her/one's/ their /earnestness has down voted my answer.

Comment: *One* is not "dated", and your example sounds utterly awful.

Comment: One's and oneself , not "one" when used in relation to.     " one " as subject. Please explain why awful.

Comment: None of the answers  reveals the problem encountered with one as subject.

Answer (score -3):

One, in that context seems to me to be an attributive, and given it refers to an individual person this would also make it a placeholder for a name.  So an Adjective i guess. 
I see how it also is the noun, where "One" is refering to a person who is subjectively involved in a way that is not quite the same as saying " Any person...".

So imagine you are writing rules for a holy order of oracles, whom are all female, then you can use she and her.

Comment: Additionally, he/him can be used in place of always including she and her.    This in recent years has been attacked, but historically is the practice.  If anyone gives you trouble doing that you could try saying " Women are worthy of the extra attention, while males are generally simple."

Comment: "WHO all female", not "whom"!

Comment: @RyanEyestone: It is historically the practice in American English, but not British, where repeating _one_ has always been normal. Reading _one ... he_ is still disconcerting to me.

Comment: @ColinFine Surely it is disconcerting to careful writers everywhere.

Comment: This answer is purely opinion. Answers should be backed up with references to reputable sources.